# Method to optimize PySpark dataframe saving time

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm running a notebook on Azure databricks using a multinode cluster with 1 driver and 1-8 workers(each with 16 cores and 56 gb ram). Reading the source data from Azure ADLS which has 30K records. Notebook is consist of few transformation steps, also using two UDFs which are necessary for code implementation. While my entire transformation steps are running within 12 minutes(which is expected), it is taking more than 2 hours to save the final dataframe to ADSL Delta table. I'm providing some code snippet here(can't provide the entire code), suggest me ways to reduce this dataframe saving time.

```
# All the data reading and transformation code
# only one display statement before saving it to delta table. Up to this statement it is taking 12 minutes to run
data.display()
```

```
# Persisting the data frame
from pyspark import StorageLevel
data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

```
# Finally writing the data to delta table
# This part is taking more than 2 hours to run
# Persist Brand Extraction Output
(
  data
  .write
  .format('delta')
  .mode('overwrite')
  .option('overwriteSchema', 'true')
  .saveAsTable('output_table')
)
```

Another save option tried but not much improvement

```
mount_path = "/mnt/********/"
table_name = "********"
adls_path = mount_path + table_name
(data.write.format('delta').mode('overwrite').option('overwriteSchema', 'true').save(adls_path))
```

Comment: Try with `.save(deltaTablePath)`. Also check whether this can be used in your usecase `.option("mergeSchema", "true").mode("append")`

Comment: Tried .save(...) but still it is taking 2 hours and 10 minutes to save